# Funny problem with question - is this site virus safe?

Tags: support

I tried to see [Drupal virus problem](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80105/drupal-virus-problem) question, but I can't - my firewall blocks it due to virus alert. Maybe it's over-sensitive, but I wanted to bring it to attention. Is this question safe and I'm getting false positive?

Answer (score 4):

The code in that question is malicious - so your anti-virus software is blocking access to it, nothing more than that :)

The site itself is safe; it would never attempt to *execute* that javascript, it's correctly escaped for display. But anti-virus runs on a 'monkey-see-monkey-do' premise. It sees bad code, so it blocks it, regardless of the execution context.

I've deleted it anyway, keeping it would serve no purpose I can think of

Comment: Oh, OK. Better safe than sorry, I guess. But it's good to know question was safe to see and nobody got harmed.

Comment: Yeah, actually you could consider it proof that your AV is working (if a bit over-eagerly). That's always good to know

Comment: seems this appeared again http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80108/when-im-login-as-admin-then-display-some-issue-like-echo . Is there any way to flag for attention when I cannot open question's page? Just to make sure someone will check post for security. Or should I just take it and do not bother?

Comment: You could always turn your AV off...kidding ;) Don't worry about it, they'll get picked up by those of us on macs/*nix. And if not I'm fairly sure we'll get some more meta posts about them

Comment: Well no, I cannot even if I want. I have no access or control over it, as this particular mechanism is at firewall/proxy, not local computer.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a user's server was compromised with one of the various JS injection hacks.  The user posted the code that was added to the page, and this triggered your AV.

Clive has already deleted the question.

If this happens again, flag the post, and one of the mods will take care of it.

Comment: How can I flag a post I cannot see? Is there any option to flag from the question list?

Comment: @Mołot you can specify it through "other"

Comment: @Bala no, when I cannot open question's page I can't.